# Trying to convert individual components into AMP rather than all components on page in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amp-html

I'm trying to run this page as an AMP on '/' route but I only want to run the Article component as AMP. The three components are rendered conditionally based on `viewType`.

```
export const config = { amp: true };

const BlogDesignArticlePage = (
  componentProp:
    | ICategoryLandingPageProps
    | IBlogCategoryPageData
    | IArticlePageProps
) => {
  const { isCurrentBlog, category, subCategory, viewType } = componentProp;
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCurrentBlog) {
      window.location.href = `${BASE_PROD_URL}/${category}`;
    }
  }, [isCurrentBlog]);

  if (!viewType) {
    return <ErrorPage />;
  }

  if (viewType === 'designCategory') {
    const {
      title,
      subtitle,
      header_image: headerImage,
      products,
      navigation,
      categories,
      content,
      faq,
      explore_categories: exploreCategories,
      mood_board_img: moodBoardImage,
      countryCode,
      meta_description: metaDescription,
      meta_title: metaTitle,
      moodboard_mobile_img_url: moodBoardMobileImageUrl,
      moodboard_content: moodBoardContent,
      href_lang_urls: hrefLangUrl,
    } = componentProp as ICategoryLandingPageProps;

    return (
      <CategoryLP
        title={title}
        subtitle={subtitle}
        headerImageUrl={headerImage}
        products={products}
        breadcrumbItemList={navigation}
        categories={categories}
        content={content}
        faq={faq}
        exploreCategories={exploreCategories}
        moodBoardImg={moodBoardImage}
        countryCode={countryCode}
        metaDescription={metaDescription}
        metaTitle={metaTitle}
        moodBoardMobileImage={moodBoardMobileImageUrl}
        moodBoardContent={moodBoardContent}
        category={category}
        subCategory={subCategory}
        hreflangUrls={hrefLangUrl}
        region="en-in"
      />
    );
  }

  if (viewType === 'blogCategory' || viewType === 'blogSubCategory') {
    const {
      hero_config,
      featured_articles,
      latest_articles,
      categories,
      seo_content,
      other_trending_articles,
      faq,
      breadcrumbs,
    } = componentProp as IBlogCategoryPageData;

    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Head>
          {/* <link rel="stylesheet" src="../../styles/App.scss" /> */}
        </Head>
        <Header />
        <Hero
          breadCrumbNavigation={breadcrumbs}
          heroDescription={hero_config?.hero_description}
          heroHeader={hero_config?.hero_header}
          heroImageDesktop={
            hero_config?.hero_image_desktop || CATEGORY_HEADER_DEAFULT_IMAGE
          }
          heroImageMobile={
            hero_config?.hero_image_mobile || CATEGORY_HEADER_DEAFULT_IMAGE
          }
        />
        {featured_articles && (
          <FeaturedArticleSection articleList={featured_articles} />
        )}
        {latest_articles && (
          <LatestArticles
            articleList={latest_articles}
            isBlogHome={false}
            categories={categories}
            sectionTitle="Latest Articles"
          />
        )}
        {categories && (
          <OtherCategory isBlogHome={false} categories={categories} />
        )}
        {other_trending_articles && (
          <TrendingArticlesWrapper>
            <SimilarStories
              similarArticles={other_trending_articles}
              title="Other Trending Articles"
            />
          </TrendingArticlesWrapper>
        )}
        <PlatformFeaturesWrapper>
          <PlatformFeaturesAmp />
        </PlatformFeaturesWrapper>
        <SubscriptionBanner />
        <PartnerVoice slug="en-us" />
        {seo_content && (
          <TrendsContentWrapper>
            <TrendsContent
              hasWrapperClass={false}
              trendData={seo_content}
              className="category-seo-content"
            />
          </TrendsContentWrapper>
        )}
        {faq && (
          <TrendsContentWrapper>
            <FaqSection
              hasWrapperClass={false}
              faqData={faq}
              className="category-faq"
            />
          </TrendsContentWrapper>
        )}
        <AmpPreFooter />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }

  if (viewType === 'blogArticle') {
    const {
      breadcrumbs,
      author_info,
      article_content,
      share_info,
      article_reading_time,
      article_category,
      article_views,
      article_title,
      similarArticles,
      id,
      tags,
      meta_title,
      meta_description,
      article_preview_image_desktop,
    } = componentProp as IArticlePageProps;

    const articleCode = router.query?.category as string;

    const newBreadCrumbList = breadcrumbs.filter(
      (crumb: { name: string }) => crumb.name !== 'Blog'
    );

    return (
      <>
        {/* <Header /> */}
        <Article
          breadcrumbs={newBreadCrumbList}
          authorInfo={author_info}
          socialShareData={share_info}
          articleReadingTime={article_reading_time}
          articleCategory={article_category}
          articleViews={article_views}
          articleTitle={article_title}
          articleBody={article_content}
          articleCode={articleCode}
          similarArticles={similarArticles}
          articleId={id}
          tags={tags}
          metaTitle={meta_title}
          metaDescription={meta_description}
          featuredImage={article_preview_image_desktop}
        />
        {/* <PreFooter /> */}
        <AmpPreFooter />
      </>
    );
  }
  return null;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async context => {
  const category = context.params?.category as string;

  try {
    if (category === ' textile') {
      // Avoid making unnecessary API Call
      throw new Error('Textile Page route');
    }
    const response = await fetchBlogOrDesignOrArticlePage(category);

    if (!response.status) {
      throw response.msg;
    }
    const viewType = response.data.view_type;
    const similarArticles = response.data.pageData.similar_articles
      ? response.data.pageData.similar_articles
      : [];
    const articleData = response.data.pageData.article_data;
    return {
      props: {
        ...response.data.pageData,
        ...articleData,
        viewType,
        similarArticles,
        category,
        subCategory: '',
        isActiveCategory: true,
        isCurrentBlog: false,
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      props: {
        title: '',
        subtitle: '',
        header_image: '',
        get_in_touch_url: '',
        products: [],
        navigation: [],
        categories: [],
        content: [],
        faq: [],
        explore_categories: [],
        mood_board_img: '',
        meta_title: '',
        meta_description: '',
        moodboard_mobile_img_url: '',
        moodboard_content: '',
        isActiveCategory: false,
        href_lang_urls: {},
        isCurrentBlog: category === 'textile',
      },
    };
  }
};

export default BlogDesignArticlePage;
```

I have tried doing `export const config = { amp: true };` inside components rather than on page but it hasn’t worked. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).